# graph representation with minimum cost (time and space)

Tags: java, list, graph, matrix

i have to represent a graph in java but neither as an adjacency list nor an adjacency matrix..

the basic idea is that if

```
deg[i]
```

is that exit degree of vertex i, then its neigboors can store in

`edges[i][j]` where

```
i <= j <= deg[i]
```

, but given that

```
edges[][]
```

must be initialized with some values i dont know how to make it differ from an adjacency matrix..

any suggestions?

Comment: Does it have to be an array? Can it be an ArrayList?

Comment: the thing with lists is about the time cost. is arrayList better than adjacency lists in time cost?

Answer (score 1):

In my knowledge there are only two ways to represent a graph in a language.

- Either Use Adjacency matrix
- Or Use Incidence matrix

You can make an incidence matrix like

> E1  E2   E3  E4
>        
>    V1     1   2   1
>     1         
>    V2     2
>     1   2   1        
>    V3
>       1   1    1    2      
>    
>    V4     1   1    2    1

Comment: Adjancency list, incidence list are both also valid graph reprentations. In fact the Adjacency list is one of the most common.

Answer (score 0):

You are fighting against lower bounds on this question.  The two main representations of the graph are already very good for their respective use.

- Adjacency list, minimizes space.  You will be hard pressed to use less memory than 1 pointer per edge. Space: O(V*E). Search: O(V)
- Adjacency matrix, is very fast, at the cost of v^2 space. Space: O(V^2). Search: O(1)

So, to make something that is better for both space and time you will have to combine the ideas from both.  Also realize will just have better practical performance, theoretically you will not improve O(1) search, or O(V*E) size.

My idea would be to store all the graph nodes in one array. Then for each Node have an adjacency list represented as a bit vector.  This would essentially be a matrix like representation, but only for those nodes that exist in the graph, giving you a smaller size than a matrix.  Search would be slightly improved over an Adjacency list as the query node can be tested against the bit vector.

Also check out [sparse matrix representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix).